# Default MySQL Keyword

Tags: mysql, syntax, keyword

In this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    content TEXT,
    date_added DATE NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

InnoDB is the storage engine and UTF-8 is the character set.

But what does the `DEFAULT` keyword represent? What effect does it have in the above statement?

Comment: Not `DEFAULT` but `DEFAULT CHARSET` - this is ONE solid keyword, which consists from 2 separate words. Like datatype `INT UNSIGNED` which is 2 words but one keyword.

Answer (score 3):

It's an optional keyword that goes with `CHARSET`, which is setting the default character set for all columns that contain character data and don't specify an explicit `CHARACTER SET`.

It doesn't mean anything by itself, there's no difference between `CHARSET` and `DEFAULT CHARSET`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That's what threw me off, the fact that it's two words but acts as a single keyword along with CHARSET. 

Comment: There are many optional keywords in SQL, to allow writing more English-like statements.

Comment: Which are the most common ones?

Comment: `ENGINE` can be `STORAGE ENGINE`. When you define a table using a `SELECT` query, you can have an optional `AS` before the query. There are other optional `[DEFAULT]` keywords at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Comment: When doing a `SELECT`, you can optionally have `AS` before table and column aliases.